# Closing a form after (async)await

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, vsto

Here's my winform, which is opened from a VSTO add-on. It has a button on it which fires an async task (an async web request) and if the response is satisfactory it closes the form:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private async void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = await doAsyncRequest();
        if (response.Worked())
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything's fine until reaching the `Close()` call to close the form, here's the the exception: `System.InvalidOperationException - Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MyForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Other async/await stuff is working fine when launched directly from the VSTO ribbon.

Comment: That *should* be okay, assuming `doAsyncStuff` is just returning a `Task<T>`, and that `Btn_Click` is called on the UI thread...

Comment: This bombs when you close the window yourself *before* your code does.  And there's another thread around that keeps the app from terminating.  Use the debugger's Debug + Windows + Threads to see what threads are running.  And the form's Enabled property to avoid this kind of DoEvents failure mode.

Comment: What is the doAsyncStuff doing? Is it accessing the UI in any way?

Comment: No, it's basically just an async web request. I'll add some more information to the original question which I didn't think was relevant but evidently must be.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that Close() will destroy visual elements--and visual elements can only be accessed from the thread that created them.  Thus you must switch to the main thread in order to close your form.

While I'm pretty new to this stuff I have so far been successfully handling this sort of thing with:

```
delegate void DoUICallback();
```

and from within the async code:

```
DoUICallback Callback = new DoUICallback(CallClose);
```

and finally:

```
private void CallClose()
{
  // Whatever UI code you want to do
  Close();
}
```

I haven't tried closing the form this way, all my stuff has been displaying what I can immediately and putting the database stuff into the background to be displayed as it's loaded.